# Rest API for getting attribute option information

Tags: magento2, attributes, rest-api, list

I want to get a list of all attributes.

I know that `domain.com/rest/V1/products/attributes/{{ATTRIBUTE_ID}}/options` will grab an the attribute options, but how do i get a list of all attributes so I can know what all of the attribute_ids are?

(I don't really want to grab by attribute-set, I want all eav attributes, including all attributes that are not product attributes).

Edit:
`/rest/V1/products/attributes/?searchCriteria` gets me close

Edit2:
A quick look at `/Magento/Eave/etc/webapi.xml` is leaving me thinking this is not something that can be done out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All Category Attributes

https://example.com/rest/V1/categories/attributes?searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=attribute_id&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=ASC

> All Product Attributes

https://example.com/rest/V1/products/attributes?searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=attribute_id&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=ASC

(**Note:** you will get attribute options within list API.no need to call for single attribute)
For Remaining you have to create custom there is no API for getting all EAV attributes

> Eav

```
GET    /V1/eav/attribute-sets/list
GET    /V1/eav/attribute-sets/:attributeSetId
```